# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2 Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: NonReportingPartyLEI is bigint picture]

I'm trying to select the following and gets an error for 
converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

```
SELECT distinct NonReportingPartyLEI, NonReportingPartyCountry
  FROM [AVA_DWH].[dbo].[Dynamic_Data]
  where NonReportingPartyLEI in (5116854,
5124879,
5111791,
5126782,
5118409,
5120091,
5121994,
5113143,
5122326)
```

**Columns data types:**
NonReportingPartyLEI (bigint, null)
NonReportingPartyCountry (nvarchar(200), null)

Please help
Thanks!

Comment: mysql <> sql server, please don't tag products not involved

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please dont tag other RDBMS. This looks like a SQL Server query; I have removed MySQL tag.

Comment: `NonReportingPartyLEI and ...` you are missing a condition here.

Comment: thanks for correcting my tags. what condition I'm missing? 
NonReportingPartyLEI is a bigint, I would add a capture if I knew how to add pictures to a comment her..

Comment: `where NonReportingPartyLEI and` since sql server doesn't have a boolean datatype, you need a condition.

Comment: oh right, I've edited the above query.

Comment: Is `[Dynamic_Data]` a view, by any chance?

Comment: yes it is a view

Comment: The error comes from the view (if indeed NonReportingPartyLEI is a bigint), please add the code for the view.

Comment: I don't have permission to edit the view code.
any idea for solution?

Comment: Not without the code for the view. Somewhere in there there's an implicit conversion from `nvarchar` to `bigint`. That needs to be corrected.

Comment: ok thanks I hoped there is a solution as a viewer. case closed